# Understanding list iteration and function calls in Racket

Tags: racket

I'm trying to implement a prolog-like program using Racket. I'm very new to the language still. I was able to write the `=or`, `=and`, and `==` that are seen in the `=parent` function below, but I'm having trouble with `query` and I feel like it's a basic misunderstanding given my beginner's status with the language.

Here's the parent function:

```
(define (=parent x y)
   (=or (=and (== x "Cronus") (== y "Zeus"))
        (=and (== x "Zeus") (== y "Athena"))
        (=and (== x "Athena") (== y "Erichthonius"))))
```

Here's the expected use:

```
(query (option) (=parent "Zeus" option))
```

...which will succeed when `option` is `Athena`.

I've given it a number of different attempts, but am always getting the wrong output and behavior. I initially tried to use the local-binding of `let` but I've simplified it even further and it still isn't working:

```
(define query
  (lambda (arg1 arg2)
    (for/list ([i (in-list arg1)])
      (ormap (λ (x) arg2 x) i))))
```

I also took the approach of defining `option` as so:

```
(define (option)
  (list '(Zeus Athena Erichthonius Cronus)))
```

Running the query code as shown above always results with an output of `'(Zeus)`.

In the debugger, when I set a breakpoint at the `for/list` line, I see `i => (Zeus Athena Erichthonius Cronus)` and `i` never changes before `query` returns. I thought the code I wrote would iterate through the list, assigning `i` to each element, but that's not the case here. So where am I going wrong?

In addition, in each step through the debugger, I never enter the `(=parent x y)` function. And I'm not understanding why it isn't being called.

My last question: why can't I define `option` using a `list` of strings? (it produces:  ormap: contract violation, expected: list? given: "Zeus"

```
(define (option)
  (list "Zeus" "Athena" "Erichthonius" "Cronus"))
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a helpful bit of direction.

Comment: @PetSerAl post an answer!